# How to make a container comunicate with non-containerized application (Ex database)

Tags: docker, docker-network, linux-containers

I'm trying to understand how a containerized application can communicate
with a non-containerized application, for example a non-containerized database
that could be on the same host or not.
I would like to know which command or setting is needed to make this happen.

Comment: Is the communication outgoing from the container, incoming to the container, or both?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson Both

Comment: What have you already tried?  Because a container trying to talk to an external database should just work with no special setup at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze I know that it's work, I just want to know what is the best way to set up this link, write directly inside the container, passing through environment variables ... ?

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use host network https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

In this way it is as if your application was installed inside the machine even if it is actually inside a container

Comment: Thanks,yes but it's help non-containerized app to comunicate with container but how to make container talk to the uncontainerized application.

Comment: your app should have a configuration file that points to the db inside the container, change it and point to db.
I suggest you to use a dockerfile to change the configuration of your app

Comment: Ok, but it's possible to pass it through an environment variable rather than write it inside the container?

Comment: depends on the type of image you are using, you can go to the docker hub or the repository where you found it and read the guide that is usually written to create an image or read the dockerfile of the image itself can sometimes help

Answer (score 0):

Docker container can communicate with outside world without any problem
as long as the host that contains the daemon can communicate with the target host.

In the other direction, the container must publish a port through which it becomes accessible from outside

Comment: Yes i understand, but i'm trying to find the best way to create that link. For example if I have several containers that have to be connected to an non-containerized app. What is the best way to configure that link ?

Comment: you can create a proxy container that publish a port for the outside and redirect received request to other containers witch  not publish any port.